# How can I make ASP.NET MVC views output unicode characters correctly?

Tags: asp.net

When I use the <%=...%> syntax and pass in a string with non-ascii characters, the string is decoded and outputed as ASCII. For example: <%="é"%> outputs é.

How can I make the views output the encoded characters instead?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to HTML encode? If your page is utf-8 there should be no problem. But if you want to HTML encode you could use `<%:` in ASP.NET 4.0:

```
<%: "é" %>
```

and:

```
<%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("é") %>
```

in older versions.

Personally I would recommend you to set the `requestEncoding` and `responseEncoding` to utf-8 in the `<globalization>` element in your web.config and put a `<meta charset="utf-8" />` (HTML5) tag in the head section of your master page and you should be fine.

Comment: Perhaps I should've mentioned that the template is outputting the contents of a Javascript string. The actual output that I'm getting is &#233. If I use HtmlUtility.HtmlEncode I now get &amp;#233 instead. Since this is in a quoted string, the encoding of the page doesn't seem to mather.

Comment: @Tristan St-Cyr, if you intend to pass any string or object to javascript I would recommend you using JSON, like this: `var jsVar = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(SomeObject) %>;`. This will ensure safe encoding of everything and you could also pass entire object graphs to javascript.

Comment: Still not working. <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("é") for example outputs: &quot;&#233;&quot;

Comment: @Tristan St-Cyr, hmm, weird. It seems that you are HTML encoding the output. Normally it should output `var jsVar = "é";`. You should not be html encoding it.