# Sending special characters to view in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a streaming service and got problems with some chars:
  `Falco - T�MA � - Mutter Der Mann Mit Dem Koks Ist Da!.mp3`
Thats what i get in the controller.
Should be: Falco - T»MA † - Mutter Der Mann Mit Dem Koks Ist Da!.mp3

`mp3model.Files.Add(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(file.Replace(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mp3BaseFolder"], "")));`

Already tried `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`.
I get the wrong encoding in the controller.

So what am I doing wrong?
Sending the string to controller;

```
function loadSiteAnimated(url, hideNav)
{
   alert(url);
   var body;
   $.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'html',
   cache: false,
   asynch: false,
   beforeSend: function () { $("#body-content").html("").fadeOut("fast"); },

  });
}
```

Request.Querystring is

```
{path=C%3a%5cUsers%5cThinkpad%5cDesktop%5cMusic%5c&name=Falco+-+T%ufffdMA+%ufffd+-+Mutter+Der+Mann+Mit+Dem+Koks+Ist+Da!.mp3&_=1427641504237}
```

Comment: try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406755/how-can-i-make-asp-net-mvc-views-output-unicode-characters-correctly

Comment: @Sardoan In that case, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I need to use

```
var path='@HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(Model.Path)';
```

before sending the path to the controller.